# How to import LD_LIBRARY_PATH for python script? No root access. No permission to restart apache server

Tags: python, postgresql, apache, cgi, web-hosting

I have a shared hosting in GoDaddy hosting service.It has the following limitations.

- No root access
- No permission to restart apache server

My hosting service system and applications specifications.

- Postgres 10.7
- python3
- OS  --  Linux version 2.6.32-896.16.1.lve1.4.54.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@buildfarm03.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)

I use a cgi script to redirect the apache server to my Python script.
When Python tries to import the psycopg2 module, the following error is thrown

```
 /home/user/python_base/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: PQescapeIdentifier
```

I exported the `postgresql/lib` path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and restarted the Python script locally and it works fine.

But since I cannot restart the apache server, I guess the process in which the apache is running does not have the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` updated. So the error persists. I have a python environment running. I copied all the library files from `postgresql/lib` to `mypythonenv/lib`, still in vain.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the environment variable in [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) *before* importing psycopg2.